# Imgur Anticontainer for DownThemAll JSON

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, reddit, imgur

I'm not totally sure how to explain this. I use DownThemAll with AntiContainer to pull every image off of a website. It was working great until about three weeks ago when everything just stopped working.

Links to Addon pages for [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/downthemall) and [AntiContainer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/downthemall-anticontainer/?src=search)

I think the relevant JSON is as follows. I can't make heads or tails of the documentation.

```
{
 "type": "redirector",
 "keepReferrer": true,
 "prefix": "imgur.com (ext redirect)",
 "pattern": "\\.[a-z0-9]{3,5}$",
 "date": 1385081055000,
 "ns": "downthemall.net",
 "useServerName": true,
 "match": "^https?://(?:[\\w\\d]+\\.)?imgur\\.com/[a-z0-9]{3,}\\.[a-z0-9]{3,5}$",
 "replacement": ""
}
```

Can someone help me out with this? I've looked ***everywhere*** for a solution, but all of them are from 2013 or so.